# Using Lerna.js and Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, lerna, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm studying about azuredevops pipelines to a new project. I'm totally new about devops.

In this project, I want to use lerna.js to manage my monorepo and my packages.

Considering that I have those three projects inside my monorepo:

- Package 1 (1.0.1)
- Package 2 (1.0.0)
- Package 3 (1.0.3)

And I want to create a new TAG, which will increase the Package 3 to (1.0.4). How can I trigger an Azure Pipeline just to Package 3? There is any guide?

I watched [one talk about monorepos](https://youtu.be/rdeBtjBNcDI?t=1669) with lerna.js and I'm trying to figure out if Azure Pipelines has one feature similar to what Sail CI does. In the exemple we have this approch:

```
tasks:
  build-package-1:
    image: sailci/demo
    when:
      paths:
        - "packages/package-1/**/*"
```

The company I'm working at is using Azure DevOps, would be awesome know if I can have that feature there.

Comment: Do you mean you need to add additional projects for each version in the same repository? Since the DevOps repo has the all history, I think you just need a project in the repo and just add Tag for each version.

Comment: Lerna.js was it own way to manage TAG across the packages. I want to make a trigger for pipelines where I can automatically deploy one project based on a new version at a particular package. I can create pipelines to do this deploy, but for now without trigger. The trigger is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing similar to that one is like @Simon Ness wrote multiple pipelines with [path filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths). Additionally if your packages have similar strucutre and require the same steps to creeate/test/publish package you should consider [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters).

The conspet toi handle packages like you described can be similar to below steps.

template.yaml

```yaml
parameters:
- name: workingDir 
  type: string
  default: package-1

steps:
- script: npm install
  workingDiretory: ${{ parameters.workingDir }}
- script: yarn install
  workingDiretory: ${{ parameters.workingDir }}
- script: npm run compile
  workingDiretory: ${{ parameters.workingDir }}
```

then pipeline for Package-1 may look like this:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - Package-1/*


steps:
- template: templates/template.yaml
  parameters:
    workingDir: Package-1
```

and for Package-2:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - Package-2/*

steps:
- template: templates/template.yaml
  parameters:
    workingDir: Package-2
```

**EDIT**

For tag part all you need to do is change trigger section:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - refs/tags/*
```

and when you create a tag and push it:

```
git tag release-05
git push origin --tags
```

your pipeline wil start:

[image: Azure DevOps release view]

However, trigger works like or condition, so for any change on master or new tag piepline will start. So if you tag another branch (not master) pipeline will start.

This is why you may need to check if your source branch is the one from trigger section:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - refs/tags/*

stages:
- stage: A
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'master')
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Foo."
```

Above pipeline will run for:

- change in master branch
- any tag pushed to server, but it runs stage A only if you push tag to master branch

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it already helped me a lot.

This way I can trigger when I have any change in my package. How can I trigger when I have changes in my package and it is only for master and a new TAG? I want to do it because I want to make one pipeline to build and deploy just one package. Your solution trigger when I have any change at master.

I found [one solution at Medium](https://medium.com/faun/azure-pipelines-and-git-tag-quirks-1daaba61713a), but I didn't understand how to put this "onlyTags" at my .yml file. Maybe my problem is syntax. Can you help me?

Comment: @MathiasGhenoAzzolini can you check my edit? Does it help you?

Comment: In my tests, this last example didn't work, It skipped all the execution for "JA" job and it was triggered three times. So I changed "master" to "'refs/heads/master'" and the job "JA" was trigger three times and the "JA" job was skipped only for the TAG event. So, I tried to put 'refs/tags/' using the `startsWith` and it triggered only for the TAG event. (But still three times, because of lerna.js). But, this solution also triggered when I did a new TAG to other packages, so it is not looking for my `path` attribute. My final code [is here](https://www.shorturl.at/wEKM4)

Comment: If you are interested to investigate it, I can share my project with you. It is an Proof Of Concept project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to define a separate pipeline for each package take a look at [paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) in CI [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

Tags can be used as a trigger by including the branch `- refs/tags/*` in the triggers section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still need to trigger when I have path, branch and new TAG.