# Lerna packages and PublishBuildArtifactsV1 Task

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-devops, yaml

We have 3 packages (A, B, C) in a repository. Each package is having dist/some-data. (And, these packages count may increase)

Hard-coding `PublishBuildArtifactsV1` with the 3 different dist paths is fine.

Is there a way, we can do ForEach loop on the `PublishBuildArtifactsV1` task with different file paths and artifact names?

Thanks in Advance,

Raag!

Comment: Hi Anuraag Vodnala, Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a separate pipeline for each package, take a look at [paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) in CI [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

Besides, if your packages have similar strucutre and require the same steps to creeate/test/publish package, you could create a template which will have a set of actions, and pass parameters across during your build, like:

deploy-xxx.yaml:

```
parameters:
  param : []

steps:
  - ${{each filename in parameters.param}}
    - scripts: 'echo ${{ filename  }}'
```

pipeline.yaml:

```
steps:
 - template: deploy-xx.yaml
   parameters:
     param: ["filaname1","filaname2","filaname3"]
```

Check the document [Solving the looping problem in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://mattvsts.github.io/2019/05/04/solving-the-looping-problem-in-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/) for some more details.

Please check the official document [Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

You could also take a look at *Krzysztof Madej's* reply in this similar question: [Using Lerna.js and Azure Devops Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783014/using-lerna-js-and-azure-devops-pipeline)